# Setting a cookie

Tags: php, cookies

Trying to learn cookies in PHP to me everything seems fine but it doesnt even set the cookie 
here is the code

```
<?php
    if (isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
        header('Location: simple.php');    
    } else {
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
                if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
                    $expire = time() + 60 * 60;
                    setcookie('user', $_POST['username'], $expire);
                } else {
                    header('Location: simple.php');
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Please Enter Your Information !';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Please Submit';
        }
    }
?>
```

#### Edit

tried

```
<?php 

  setcookie("testcookie","testvalue",0); 
  echo $_COOKIE['testcookie'];

?>
```

Result is

```
Notice: Undefined index: testcookie in /var/www/php-practice/cookies/test.php on line 1
```

and it sets the cookie `testcookie` in browser with the value `testvalue`

 Feel there is some error in `$_POST['submit']`
because

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //everything else
} else {
    echo 'Submit Button Problem !';
}
```

it prints the `Submit Button Problem !`
here is the HTML of the submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
```

Looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775512/using-ifisset-postsubmit-to-not-display-echo-when-script-is-open-is-not) and tried it but still nothing

I tried everything I could but it doesnt work 
Help !

Comment: you should use sessions, in most use-cases. in this case, I could simply create a cookie on my side and I'd be "authenticated".

Comment: What happens? Did you get redirected to simple.php or is there a message or something else? The setcookie() function looks ok.

Comment: @Prisoner just trying cookies for learning and its not working

Comment: Make sure to remove any whitespace from the beginning of your php file.

Comment: @MarcelBalzer it doesnt redirects to the simple.php

Comment: @bagonyi looked into it and theres no white space before `<?php ?>`

Comment: What is the actual error message or behaviour? DO you have errors enabled?

Comment: @DanFromGermany It doesnt show any error and yes errors are enable

Comment: On the top of the page, simply put var_dump($_COOKIE); & check what u r getting

Comment: The cookie doesn't exist at all? Is your Browser accepting cookies?

Comment: @Dev I tried this and it print `array(0) { } `

Comment: @MarcelBalzer yes my browser accepting cookies

Comment: Can you please just try following on your server: Create a file with the content: <?php setcookie("testcookie","testvalue",0); echo $_COOKIE['testcookie'];?> and put this on your server. Execute and just tell, if "testvalue" is printed.

Comment: are you getting $_POST['checkbox'] ?? please check it goes to if condition or else..

Comment: @MarcelBalzer i edited the question please have a look

Comment: Use FireBug to see the headers weather the cookies are sent and resent or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you can't set and display cookies on same page at same time.  If you set and redirect to another page or reload the page, it will show the cookie value.

```
<?php 

 setcookie("testcookie","testvalue",0); //this will work
 echo $_COOKIE['testcookie']; // won't work unless reloaded

?>
```

For your initial script. Ensure that $_POST['checkbox'] exists, is checkbox the name of your html form checkbox input?

```
//Your HTML form should include this
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkbox" /> 


 if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {

        $expire = time() + 60 * 60;
        setcookie('user', $_POST['username'], $expire);

    } else {
        header('Location: simple.php');
    }
```

Edit your HTML Form to include method="post"

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkbox" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: it doesnt go inside the `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {}`
in html form i have submit is like that `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />`

Comment: ensure your form has method="post" check my answer for modification

Answer (score 0):

The $_COOKIE is only available **after** the site was loaded.