# What is wrong with this code? (imagettftext)and like that

Tags: php

Hallo so this is what I have:

test.php

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="nick">
   <input type="submit" name="test">
</form>
```

index.php

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['test'])) {

  $bg = imagecreatefrompng('img/sygn/1.png') or die("t");
    $font = "others/rte.ttf";
    $blackColor = imagecolorallocate($bg, 47, 53, 62);
    $diamondColor = imagecolorallocate($bg, 140, 244, 226);
    $emeraldColor = imagecolorallocate($bg, 92, 244, 149);
    $goldCollor = imagecolorallocate($bg, 234, 238, 87);
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagettftext($bg, 29, 0, 5, 33, $blackColor, $font, 'Username');
    imagettftext($bg, 17, 0, 360, 83, $goldCollor, $font, '20');
    imagettftext($bg, 17, 0, 360, 43, $emeraldColor, $font, '20');
    imagettftext($bg, 28, 0, 50, 125, $diamondColor, $font, '400');
    imagepng($bg);
    imagepng($bg, "users/image.png");
    imagedestroy($bg);
}

?>
```

I would like to display the image after clicking on the button. But it doesn't work, I don't get any image only the blank side. 
If I remove if statement it works correctly.
Also if I Add:

```
echo '<input type="text">'
```

In the first line, image generator wont work as well.
Same with for example:

```
include form.php
```

This is what I get:

```
http://screenshot.net/pjg6du1
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Why do you call `imagepng` twice?

Comment: I don't get any Errors. I have tried it. andrewsi this is not important now. It work correctly if I remove if statement. This is what I get after clicking on the button http://screenshot.net/pjg6du1

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if(isset($_POST['nick']) && $_POST['nick'] != '') {
    //my code
}
```

Comment: Man, it won't work, I know it.And on this moment I would like to use button only to create the image. This have nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: so put a value in the submit element `<input type="submit" name="test" value="go">`

Comment: It is not the problem. Button works correctly even if i use     <input type="submit" name="test"> But Image won't generate

Answer (score 0):

You need to set value for your input submit as the following:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
```

Similar another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7775525/2791480)

Comment: No. It is not the problem. When I look in the code my image is generated But I don't see it.

Comment: Ok, Try to echo isset($_POST['test']) before if condition, if it's true, so it'll go through code inside if statement, that's to make sure, and let me know

Answer (score 0):

1. Check all paths are right (img, font and user directory).
2. Your if statement is correct.
3. Add

   on your page.
4. It works.

imagepng create image in the user directory but you don't display it on your page.

Correct code below :

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['test'])) {

  $bg = imagecreatefrompng('img/sygn/1.png') or die("t");
    $font = "others/rte.ttf";
    $blackColor = imagecolorallocate($bg, 47, 53, 62);
    $diamondColor = imagecolorallocate($bg, 140, 244, 226);
    $emeraldColor = imagecolorallocate($bg, 92, 244, 149);
    $goldCollor = imagecolorallocate($bg, 234, 238, 87);
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagettftext($bg, 29, 0, 5, 33, $blackColor, $font, 'Username');
    imagettftext($bg, 17, 0, 360, 83, $goldCollor, $font, '20');
    imagettftext($bg, 17, 0, 360, 43, $emeraldColor, $font, '20');
    imagettftext($bg, 28, 0, 50, 125, $diamondColor, $font, '400');
    imagepng($bg);
    imagepng($bg, "users/image.png");
    imagedestroy($bg);
}

?>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="nick">
   <input type="submit" name="test">
</form>
<img src="users/image.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well what was the problem I still can't find it? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have add a img tag below the form (see code) to see the image ? Do you see the image in your directory users ?

Comment: The path of the source on your screenshot is not correct ! The image is in users/image.png.