# Submit Button won't appear

Tags: php, onsubmit, submit-button, webclient

UPDATE: Here it is my code so far. The download buttons now appear, but the code is printing the form closing tag instead of identifying it as a closing tag. How can I correct this? Please help. Thanks in advance!!

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
    <TITLE>SAE Report</TITLE>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
   $().ready(function() {
     $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
   });
</script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<center>
<h1>SAE Report</h1>
</center>
 <form action = "" method = "post">
 <label>Report Type</label>
    <select id="report" name="report">
        <option value="none"></option>
        <option value="new">New SAEs Report</option>
        <option value="cumulative">Cumulative SAE Report</option>
    </select>
 <label>Start Date</label><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="start">
 <label>End Date</label><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="end">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
</BODY>
```

```
 <?php
 $type='';
 $start='';
 $end='';

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $type=$_POST['report'];
    $start=$_POST['start'];
    $end=$_POST['end'];

    if ($type=="cumulative"){
        echo "<form action='cumulativeRptExcel.php' method='post' name ='xls'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submitXLS' value='Download Excel'/>";
        echo "/form><br>";
        echo "<form action='cumulativeRptPDF.php' method='post' name ='xls'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submitXLS' value='Download PDF'/>";
        echo "/form><br>";
    }
    elseif($type=='new' and $start!='' and $end!=''){
        echo "<form action='newRptExcel.php' method='post' name ='xls'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submitXLS' value='Download Excel'/>";
        echo "/form><br>";
        echo "<form action='newRptPDF.php' method='post' name ='xls'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submitXLS' value='Download PDF'/>";
        echo "/form><br>";
    }
    elseif($type="new" and ($start=='' or $end=='')){
        echo "You need to select START and END date for the report";
    }   

}


?>
```

The report.php files contains the code to generate the excel or pdf file and make it downloadable to the user. When running those files by themselves it generates the files just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using if(isset($\_POST\['submit'\])) to not display echo when script is open is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775512/using-ifisset-postsubmit-to-not-display-echo-when-script-is-open-is-not)  (You have to give your submit input a name for it to be available using `$_POST`)

Comment: Here it updated code. But now php is printing the form closing tag (/form>) instead of identifying it as closing tag.

Comment: That's great news that the `if` statement is working properly now. The `/form>` issue is because you are missing the `<` in your html. `echo "/form><br>";` should be `echo "</form><br>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It prints `/form>` because from your codes that's what you asked it to print. You echoed out `"/form><br>";` instead of `"</form><br>";` in every line that I can see. Simply add `<` to fix that

Comment: Please vote to close instead of answering typo questions.

Answer (score 0):

Change your submit button from:

```
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

to

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

The reason behind this is the $_POST variable will only have elements that had a name inside the previous form. In your example the submit button does not have a name.

Comment: Ohh nice, thank you!!  The buttons are displaying but now it prints on the screen the closing form tag instead of identifying it as a closing tag.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Replace the echo "/form><br>"; for echo "</form><br>"; You are missing a closing tag