# php - submit button is not working in isset

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to add a form in my html which will get 12 input box and save it to mysql. but its echoing failed as because of submit button perhaps. because in if for the isset submit button the else is forwarding message. **Code for my html**

```
<body class="templatemo-bg-image-2">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">         
        <form class="form-horizontal templatemo-contact-form-1" role="form" action="input.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1 class="margin-bottom-15">Marketing Samurai 2017</h1>
                    <h2 class="margin-bottom-15">Registration form</h2>
                    <p>This contact form is provided by <a href="#">templatemo</a> that can be used for your websites. Credit goes to <a rel="nofollow" href="http://unsplash.com">Unsplash</a> for the background image.</p>
                </div>

            <hr>
            <h4 class="margin-bottom-15">Team Info</h4>
            <hr>
            </div>              
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">                   
                <label for="name" class="control-label">University Name</label>
                <div class="templatemo-input-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-university"></i>
                    <input name="uname" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="">
                </div>                                                          
              </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">                   
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Team</label>
                <div class="templatemo-input-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                    <input name="tname" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="">
                </div>                                                          
              </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">                   
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Trix Id</label>
                <div class="templatemo-input-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
                    <input name="tcode" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Bkash transection Code">
                </div>                                                          
              </div>              
            </div>
            <h4 class="margin-bottom-15">Leader Info</h4>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">                   
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="templatemo-input-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    <input name="lname" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="">
                </div>                                                          
              </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">                   
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="templatemo-input-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                    <input name="lmail" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="">
                </div>                                                          
              </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">                   
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Contact</label>
                <div class="templatemo-input-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                    <input name="lcont" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="">
                </div>                                                          
              </div>              
            </div>
            <h4 class="margin-bottom-15">1st Member Info</h4>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">                   
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="templatemo-input-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    <input name="m1name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="">
                </div>                                                          
              </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">                   
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="templatemo-input-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                    <input name="m1mail" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="">
                </div>                                                          
              </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">                   
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Contact</label>
                <div class="templatemo-input-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                    <input name="m1cont" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="">
                </div>                                                          
              </div>              
            </div>
            <h4 class="margin-bottom-15">2nd Member Info</h4>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">                   
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="templatemo-input-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    <input name="m2name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="">
                </div>                                                          
              </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">                   
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="templatemo-input-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                    <input name="m2mail" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="">
                </div>                                                          
              </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">                   
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Contact</label>
                <div class="templatemo-input-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                    <input name="m2cont" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="">
                </div>                                                          
              </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">></button>
              </div>
            </div>              
          </form>             
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code for php**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$con){

echo 'Not Connected To Server';
}
    if (!mysqli_select_db ($con,'test')) {

    echo 'Database Not Selected';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){


    $uni = $_POST['uname'];
    $team = $_POST['tname'];
    $trix = $_POST['tcode'];
    $leader = $_POST['lname'];
    $lemail = $_POST['lmail'];
    $leadercon = $_POST['lcont'];
    $mname = $_POST['m1name'];
    $memail = $_POST['m1mail'];
    $mcon = $_POST['m1cont'];
    $mname3 = $_POST['m2name'];
    $memail3 = $_POST['m2mail'];
    $mcon3 = $_POST['m2cont'];



    $sql = "INSERT INTO 'memberdetails' (uninam, team, trixid, mem, mail, cont, mem1, mail1, con1, mem2, mail2, con2) VALUES ('$uni', '$team', '$trix', '$leader', '$lemail', '$leadercon', '$mname', '$memail', '$mcon', '$mname3', '$memail3', '$mcon3' )";




        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
        echo 'Not Inserted';
    }

        else
    {

    echo 'Inserted Successfully';
}

header("refresh:2; url=index.html");

}   else {
echo "failed";
}
```

I haven't made any validation yet. and I am trying with msqli and database, table is connecting then why the error is coming? I just made the submit button just to insert docs. whats should I do to prevent the fail message. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using if(isset($\_POST\['submit'\])) to not display echo when script is open is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775512/using-ifisset-postsubmit-to-not-display-echo-when-script-is-open-is-not)

Answer (score 0):

Submit must be `<input>` with name or it won't be available using `$_POST['submit']`

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
```

Comment: `<button type="submit"></button>`, will do the same as `<input type="submit">`. So this answer do not makes sense.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775512/using-ifisset-postsubmit-to-not-display-echo-when-script-is-open-is-not

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "submit" text from name of form button and  replace with another text

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit" name="form_sumit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">></button>
```

Comment: did you change? if (isset($_POST['<replace text that you have in form button>]))