# How to check for empty form variable on page load

Tags: php

I have a html form that is checked by PHP. When the page loads php errors stating missing variable because form has not been submitted.
It works fine once I put something in the form and submit. But on first page load it errors.

Error on page load
Notice: Undefined index: sk in index.php on line 65
Notice: Undefined index: sk in index.php on line 78

```
<form action=# method="post">
Source Key: <input type="text"  name="sk">
</br>
<input type="submit">
</form>



<?php


     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        $test = $_POST['sk'];//assigning your input value

        if(isset($test))
        {
            $fr=fopen("php://stdin","r");   // open file pointer
            $input = fgets($fr,128);        // read 128 char max
            $input = rtrim($input);         // trim any trailing spaces
            fclose ($fr);                   // close the file handle
            $result =  $input;              // return the text 
        }
    } 
?>

You have entered : <?php echo $_POST["sk"]; 
echo "</br></br>";
```

Comment: `You have entered : <?php echo $_POST["sk"]; 
echo "</br></br>";` should be `You have entered : <?php echo isset($_POST["sk"]) ? $_POST["SK"] : ""; 
echo "</br></br>";`

Comment: thanks devpro worked great

Answer (score 1):

You can use isset

```
$value = (isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : 'alternative';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to name your submit

```
<input type="submit">
```

to:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

**EDITED**

then replace that part of ur php with:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "You have entered : ";
    echo $_POST['sk'];
    echo "</br></br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Your submit button does not need a name...

Comment: @TimHinz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775512/using-ifisset-postsubmit-to-not-display-echo-when-script-is-open-is-not

Comment: @TimHinz Actually it does, because of the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` part (Although we both know that there's also an issue in this part of the code `echo $_POST["sk"]`)

Comment: @AlonEitan Yeah idk why he downvoted me for that when it's common knowledge...

Comment: LMAO the only reason he needs it is because @AlonEitan is right. Otherwise there is 0 reason to name a submit button. In HTML 5 you do NOT need to name a submit button under normal circumstances.

Comment: @TimHinz In the code he provided, he obviously requires it which is why I mentioned it. Had it not been needed I wouldn't have replied

Comment: And you didn't point that out because? You linked to a 7 year old question that in no way pointed out that he did that.

Comment: U r right but not related to submit

Comment: @TimHinz He didn't name his submit while using isset so I told him he has to name it. I don't understand what you're trying to argue here when we both know that isset submit wont work without having named your submit button.

Comment: Because until @AlonEitan pointed out im pretty sure you were just taking a guess... lol